# Delphi property editor like collapsible composite value handling by TValueListEditor (or another component) in Delphi

Tags: delphi, vcl

Is there any way to set up the VCL TValueListEditor component to handle some composite element values like the property editor does in the RAD Studio IDE? (little plus sign beside the value to dropdown/collapse the items for the contained values) I know there is the TPropItem.editStyle = esEllipsis to handle composite values in external dialogs. But I would like to use this collapsible feature.
And inline custom editors. For example, a custom draw TCombobox component for line style selection. Is it not supported inline, just by the ellipsis feature? Or is there another well-known but free component that will provide this functionality?

Comment: Your question about TValueListEditor is fine, but you can't ask for a recommendation for an alternative here according to the [help]. I've removed that sentence.

Comment: @KenWhite And how can I let to know about the solution if these requirements can be just satisfied by another component. I don't understand and accept this rule.

Comment: Doesn't matter whether you understand or accept it. It's the rule here. Again, see the [help/on-topic], which says very clearly and specifically that you can't ask that here. If you don't like it, feel free to go somewhere else.

Comment: @KenWhite If you look around, large number of answers recommend alternative solutions here. It is more likely this component does not do this work. Solution : recommend an altrnative.

Comment: I've rephrased your recommendation request to comply with this site's guidelines.

Comment: Also, if *you'll* look around, I'm pretty familiar with the way this site works, thanks.